# Is there a way to get the progress for move and delete operation in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, fs, fs-extra

Currently, I am using fs.move and fs.remove (from fs-extra package) to move and delete file via nodeJS on Ubuntu 18.04, I want to monitor the progress of these operation. For copy, I can use [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-progressbar) to measure the progress for copy or file download operation. I want something similar for delete and move operations on large number of files like in Windows explorer. Any npm module suggestion that does move and delete and shows progress is welcome too.

Comment: "I am using fs.move and fs.remove"
what do you exactly mean? are these functions in the standard library?

Comment: Hey @kharandziuk, they are from npm module called fs-extra.